# How set price purchase on all my buttons in billingClient.queryProductDetailsAsync method

Tags: java, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, price

So, i'm try set price purchase on all my Buttons. I can set price only one my button, but I don't know why it doesn't work for my other buttons. Even though I do the same thing.

My PurchaseDialog:

```
public class PurchaseDialog extends DialogFragment {

    private View view;
    private AppCompatButton oneWeekPurchaseButton, oneMonthPurchaseButton, oneYearPurchaseButton;
    private BillingClient billingClient;
    private List<ProductDetails> productDetails;
    private Purchase purchase;

    static final String TAG = "InAppPurchaseTag";

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.purchase_dialog_fragment, container, false);

        oneWeekPurchaseButton = view.findViewById(R.id.oneWeekPurchaseButton);
        oneMonthPurchaseButton = view.findViewById(R.id.oneMonthPurchaseButton);
        oneYearPurchaseButton = view.findViewById(R.id.oneYearPurchaseButton);

        billingSetup();

        return view;
    }

private void billingSetup() {

    PurchasesUpdatedListener purchasesUpdatedListener = new PurchasesUpdatedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPurchasesUpdated(BillingResult billingResult, List<Purchase> purchases) {
            if (billingResult.getResponseCode() ==
                    BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK
                    && purchases != null) {
                for (Purchase purchase : purchases) {
                    // completePurchase(purchase);
                }
            } else if (billingResult.getResponseCode() ==
                    BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.USER_CANCELED) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onPurchasesUpdated: Purchase Canceled");
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "onPurchasesUpdated: Error");
            }
        }
    };

    billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(getContext())
            .setListener(purchasesUpdatedListener)
            .enablePendingPurchases()
            .build();

    billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {

        @Override
        public void onBillingSetupFinished(
                @NonNull BillingResult billingResult) {

            if (billingResult.getResponseCode() ==
                    BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                Log.i(TAG, "OnBillingSetupFinish connected");
                queryProduct();
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "OnBillingSetupFinish failed");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
            Log.i(TAG, "OnBillingSetupFinish connection lost");
        }
    });
}

private void queryProduct() {

    ImmutableList<QueryProductDetailsParams.Product> productList = ImmutableList.of(
            //Product 1
            QueryProductDetailsParams.Product.newBuilder()
                    .setProductId("premium_subs_test")
                    .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.SUBS)
                    .build(),

            //Product 2
            QueryProductDetailsParams.Product.newBuilder()
                    .setProductId("one_month_premium_test")
                    .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.SUBS)
                    .build(),

            //Product 3
            QueryProductDetailsParams.Product.newBuilder()
                    .setProductId("one_year_premuim_test")
                    .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.SUBS)
                    .build()
    );


    QueryProductDetailsParams queryProductDetailsParams = QueryProductDetailsParams.newBuilder()
            .setProductList(productList)
            .build();

    billingClient.queryProductDetailsAsync(
            queryProductDetailsParams,
            new ProductDetailsResponseListener() {
                public void onProductDetailsResponse(
                        @NonNull BillingResult billingResult,
                        @NonNull List<ProductDetails> productDetailsList) {
                    productDetails = productDetailsList;
                    oneWeekPurchaseButton.setText(productDetails.get(0).getSubscriptionOfferDetails()
                            .get(0).getPricingPhases().getPricingPhaseList().get(0).getFormattedPrice());
                    oneMonthPurchaseButton.setText(productDetails.get(0).getSubscriptionOfferDetails()
                            .get(0).getPricingPhases().getPricingPhaseList().get(0).getFormattedPrice());
                    oneYearPurchaseButton.setText(productDetails.get(0).getSubscriptionOfferDetails()
                            .get(0).getPricingPhases().getPricingPhaseList().get(0).getFormattedPrice());
                }
            }
    );

}
```

When I look in the debugger, i see that in the `queryProduct()`, in `billingClient.queryProductDetailsAsync` method my code is not executed to the end.

Here are the last two lines that the code executes:

```
                productDetails = productDetailsList;
                oneWeekPurchaseButton.setText(productDetails.get(0).getSubscriptionOfferDetails()
                        .get(0).getPricingPhases().getPricingPhaseList().get(0).getFormattedPrice());
```

It becomes clear why the subscription price is not set in the remaining buttons. But I have no idea why this is happening.

I can't fill out why all the code that is there is not executed? How fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. I use `runOnUiThread(()` :

```
             getActivity().runOnUiThread(() -> {
                    oneWeekPurchaseButton.setText(productDetails.get(2).getSubscriptionOfferDetails()
                            .get(0).getPricingPhases().getPricingPhaseList().get(0).getFormattedPrice());
                    oneMonthPurchaseButton.setText(productDetails.get(1).getSubscriptionOfferDetails()
                            .get(0).getPricingPhases().getPricingPhaseList().get(0).getFormattedPrice());
                    oneYearPurchaseButton.setText(productDetails.get(0).getSubscriptionOfferDetails()
                            .get(0).getPricingPhases().getPricingPhaseList().get(0).getFormattedPrice());
                });
```